# Python telnet connection successful

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I'm wondering if it is possible to know if my telnet connection is successful?

So, if I'm connected to my switch and if I could write commands

```
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
telnet.read_until(b"User Name:")
telnet.write(b"LOGIN\n")
telnet.read_until(b"Password:")
telnet.write(b"PASSWORD\n")
# Here I want to know if I'm connected
```

Comment: There is no such option in `telnet` lib, you can parse the server response and check if connection is successful or not, that is if server responds for successful authentication

Comment: Actually, I think some of the methods will return an `EOFError` if the connection is lost. So probably you should enclose your code in a `Try/Except` clause. See here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/telnetlib.html

Comment: @Harwee I used your tip and it is working perfectly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `read_all` if you plan on writing something after authentication. It blocks the connection until `EOF` is reached / connection is closed.

First check the output telnet server is giving when an authentication is successful using putty or something else. `read_untill` the string to be matched after authentication.

```
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
telnet.read_until(b"User Name:")
telnet.write(b"LOGIN\n")
telnet.read_until(b"Password:")
telnet.write(b"PASSWORD\n")

telnet.read_untill("string to be matched")
```

Comment: @Harwee yes you are right it's way better of using telnet.read_until() or telnet.read_very_eager()

Comment: Thanks to both of you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could go this way:

```
def is_connected(telnet_obj ):
    answer = telnet_obj.read_all()
    if "connected" in answer:             #this test condition is not real is an example
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If you observe what yout router/switch returns you can test for that condition. In this case testing for the presence of a string or lack in the answer variable.